# Вывод изображения через php скрипт

Tags: изображения, gd

Добрый день, есть код, который генерит нормальную картинку на сервере:

```
<? header('content-type: image/jpeg'); ?>
<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php"); ?>
<?$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('share.jpg');

$lightwhite = imagecolorallocate($image, 245, 179, 217);
$twhite = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($image, 36, 0, 84, 276, $twhite, "tahoma.ttf", "Санкт-Петербург");
/*imagejpeg($image, 'image.jpg', 100);*/
imagejpeg($image, '', 100);
return $image;
imagedestroy($image);?>
```

Т.е, картинка физически создаётся, и она нормально отображается (image.jpg)
Но, при попытке вывести её через вызов этого самого скрипта в браузере, выходит код картинки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как вывести картинку через прямой вызов скрипта в адресной строке?
Причем так:

```
<img src="urltosript" />
```

тоже пробовала, без толку, ничего не получается.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagejpeg.php тут то, что вам нужно на русском. Полагаю в качестве второго параметра у imagejpeg нужно передавать не '' а null

Answer (score 2):

Картинка то у вас создается, но она хранится в переменной, а браузер может подгрузить картинку только по пути.
Для того чтоб картинка отобразилась на сайте нужно ее сохранить на сервер.
[Cfile::SaveFile](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cfile/savefile.php)

И потом уже вставить путь к файлу на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Выкладываю работающий код, так и не поняла что там изменилось, но заработало

```
<? header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); ?>
<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php"); ?>
<?$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('share.jpg');

$twhite = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$from = mb_convert_encoding($_GET['form'], "utf-8", "windows-1251");
$to   = mb_convert_encoding($_GET['to'], "utf-8", "windows-1251");

imagettftext($image, 36, 0, 84, 200, $twhite, "tahoma.ttf", $from);
imagettftext($image, 36, 0, 84, 276, $twhite, "tahoma.ttf", $to);

imagejpeg($image, '', 100);
return $image;
imagedestroy($image);
```

?>